# Cannot redirect one page to another page in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I'm making a function that when i click on the image container, it will open the page with the product detail with the exact detail for each specific product. However, when i click on the image, nothing happen! Please help me to find out what wrong with my codes, thank you so much!

Product.js:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, img, price, inCart } = this.props.product;
    return (
      <ProductWrapper clasName="col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
        <div className="card">
          <ProductContext.Consumer>
            {(value) => (
              <div className="img-container p-5">
                <Router>
                  <Link to="/details">
                    <img
                      src={img}
                      alt="product"
                      className="card-img-top"
                      onClick={() => {
                        value.handleDetail(id);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Link>
                </Router>
                <button
                  className="cart-btn"
                  onClick={() => value.addToCart(id)}
                  disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                >
                  {inCart ? (
                    <p className="text-capitalize mb-0">In Cart</p>
                  ) : (
                    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                  )}
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </ProductContext.Consumer>
          <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p className="align-self-center mb-0">{title}</p>
            <h5 className="text-blue mb-0">
              <span className="mr-1">$</span>
              {price}
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProductWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

context.js:

```
class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct
  };

  getItem = (id) => {
    const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return product;
  };

  handleDetail = (id) => {
    const product = this.getItem(id);
    this.setState(() => {
      return { detailProduct: product };
    });
  };
  addToCart = (id) => {
    console.log(`hello details. id is ${id}`);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
          addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Sandbox link for better observation: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-30bgi?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a different approach where the product ID goes into the URL rather than being selected in context. This has a major advantage in that refreshing the details page means the product ID will be retained.

Here is a link to [a working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-lwglr?file=/src/App.js:9463-11696).

And here are the changes I made:

1. In the context provider, you can remove `handleDetail` since the selection will instead live in the URL:

```js
class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct
  };

  getItem = (id) => {
    const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return product;
  };

  addToCart = (id) => {
    console.log(`hello details. id is ${id}`);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

2. In the `App` component, change your `details` route to take an `itemId` parameter:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <ProductProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/productlist" component={ProductList} />
            <Route path="/details/:itemId" component={Details} />
            <Route path="*" component={() => "404 Not Found"} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ProductProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

3. In your product component, Make the `Link` point to the `details/itemId` URL and remove any need to set that ID in context:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, img, price, inCart } = this.props.product;
    return (
      <ProductWrapper clasName="col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
        <div className="card">
          <ProductContext.Consumer>
            {(value) => (
              <div className="img-container p-5">
                <Link to={`/details/${id}`}>
                  <img src={img} alt="product" className="card-img-top" />
                </Link>
                <button
                  className="cart-btn"
                  onClick={() => value.addToCart(id)}
                  disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                >
                  {inCart ? (
                    <p className="text-capitalize mb-0">In Cart</p>
                  ) : (
                    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                  )}
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </ProductContext.Consumer>
          <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p className="align-self-center mb-0">{title}</p>
            <h5 className="text-blue mb-0">
              <span className="mr-1">$</span>
              {price}
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProductWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

4. Finally, in the `Details` component, pluck the `itemId` off of the params and `find` the right item from your product list in context:

```
class Details extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { itemId } = this.props.match.params;

    return (
      <ProductContext.Consumer>
        {(value) => {
          const selected = value.products.find(
            (p) => p.id === parseInt(itemId)
          );

          if (!selected) {
            return "Bad product ID: " + itemId;
          }

          const { id, company, img, info, price, title, inCart } = selected;

          return (
            <div className="container py-5">
              {/* title */}
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto text-center text-slanted text-blue my-5">
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* end of title */}
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3">
                  <img src={img} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
                </div>
                {/* prdoduct info */}
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3 text-capitalize">
                  <h1>model : {title}</h1>
                  <h4 className="text-title text-uppercase text-muted mt-3 mb-2">
                    made by : <span className="text-uppercase">{company}</span>
                  </h4>
                  <h4 className="text-blue">
                    <strong>
                      price : <span>$</span>
                      {price}
                    </strong>
                  </h4>
                  <p className="text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0">
                    some info about product :
                  </p>
                  <p className="text-muted lead">{info}</p>
                  {/* buttons */}
                  <div>
                    <Link to="/productlist">
                      <ButtonContainer>back to products</ButtonContainer>
                    </Link>
                    <ButtonContainer
                      cart
                      disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                      onClick={() => {
                        value.addToCart(id);
                      }}
                    >
                      {inCart ? "in cart" : "add to cart"}
                    </ButtonContainer>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </ProductContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, i don't really understand what this line does " const { itemId } = this.props.match.params;" . Can you explain?

Comment: That’s destructuring assignment. It’s basically the same as doing const itemId = this.props.match.params.itemId. That’s the place in React props that the router will put any url parameters.

Comment: Sure! If this answer worked for you please mark it as the solution